# How can I cut an edge from a plane?

Tags: knife-tool

I wonder what's the best workflow for a such basic task:

[image]

[image]

I want that the plane would have the same two corners. I got stuck at the 7th step.

Two questions:

1. How can I cut that duplicated edge from a plane?
2. Is there a faster way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Hello and welcome. In future please prefer writing the text describing the workflow as actual text in the body of the question, rather than inside images. It makes it easier to fix any mistakes or typos, and also makes the question indexable, so it is searchable and easier to find for future users and people with similar issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>, 1-segment *Vertex Bevel*:

[image]

You can adjust to precision in the operator's <kbd>F9</kbd> *Adjust Last Operation* panel.

Thanks to @John Eason for the reminder.. While modelling, always have your object's *Scale* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> applied to (1,1,1) for predictable results from operations and modifiers.

Edit: The shipped add-on 'TinyCAD' can find the projected intersections between lines, and insert vertices at the closest approach. If you have a lot of that to do, you could set up shortcuts for that.

Without add-ons, this could be a way? There's probably a better one..

[image]

With Snap set.. 'To: Vertex' and 'With: Active'

- <kbd>K</kbd> cut an arbitrary edge, to insert vertices
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicate the vertices of the template edge.
- <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> with and <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>, switching active vertices, snap to the target corner, one dimension at a time
- Snap the pre-cut vertices to the duplicate, and <kbd>M</kbd> > 'By Distance' merge everything down.

Comment: Just apply the scale first in object mode (CTRL-A) if the plane isn't a square or the bevel won't be at 45 degrees!

Comment: Oh come on guys, how come there are no upvotes? I'm offended on Robin's behalf :)).

Comment: (seems to work)

Comment: Nice. Thanks. I guess that's the answer, but could you also help me with the first question? I might use it for other things in modelling. Cheers!

Comment: Also is there a way to add new vertices on the plane edge where they intersect with duplicated edge?

Comment: Thank You Very Much Robin! Very helpful. Have a great one!